# Check if a variable is boolean

Tags: matlab

how to check if a variable is  `boolean` in MATLAB?

I have a function

```
function myFunc(myBoolean)
  if myBoolean~=true && myBoolean~=false
  assert(false,'variable should be boolean);
end
x = test(myBoolean);
```

How to improve?, is there a function to check if a variable isn't true/false?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`isa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isa.html?refresh=true) function. For your case (from the help file), you would use:

```
isa(true(2,3),'logical')
ans = 
      1
```

There is also the dedicated [`islogical`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/islogical.html) function.

```
islogical(true(2,3))
ans = 
      1
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no "Boolean" type or class in Matlab. As @craigm has indicated, there is a [`logical`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logical.html) class in which `true` and `false` reside. A problem that can occur, however, is something like this:

```
test = 1;
if test == true
    class(test)
end
```

Is `test` Boolean? As I'm sure you know, the `if` statement will evaluate to `true` and `class(test)` will return `'double'`, not `'logical'`. This is a design choice on the part of The MathWorks and fits with most other programming languages: `0` and `1` from any type are commonly used for true and false. (`uint8(1) == 1` also returns `true` – values, not the class, are compared.)

So, yes, if you know that your code actually is using logical values to represent Booleans (a good idea in many cases) then [`islogical`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/islogical.html) is all you need (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/determine-if-arrays-are-logical.html) for even more examples). However, a more general (and vectorized) solution might be:

```
isBoolean = @(x)islogical(x) || isnumeric(x) && all(x(:)==0 | x(:)==1)
```

Then the following all return logical `true`:

```
isBoolean(true)
isBoolean(false)
isBoolean(zeros(1,3))
isBoolean(eye(3))
isBoolean(uint8(1))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[`class`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/class.html)** to get the type of variable as a string and then compare that string with `'logical'` to determine if the variable is a boolean one or not -

```
strcmp(class(myBoolean),'logical')
```